# Gettng data from external link in magento

Tags: magento, url, external

My requirement is to read data from an external link provided. I know about this `file_get_contents()` in normal PHP, but is it possible in Magento?
 If Some core functionality can provide me this.

All the help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See This [link](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/accessing-an-external-database-from-your-magento-module/).

Comment: What if the external database table is unknown ?